# How to unscrew this uncommon type of screw?

Tags: tools, screws, bulb, lamp, screwdriver

The staircase light next to my flat broke down and I would like to fix it. The ceiling lamp is pictured below:

[image: The Lamp]

I have a problem with unscrewing the screw. The screw is of rather peculiar shape with a little bit of space on the side and a full middle, reverse to a normal screw. I attempt to show this in the picture below:

[image]

I tried to budge it from left and right with a small screw driver but it doesn't work. I would be very grateful for any advice on how to unscrew this things. If someone could kindly point me to a tool / special screwdriver that I could cheaply buy on eBay to move this thing it would be amazing :)

Comment: Have you tried needlenose pliers?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the ones I have a little to big to fit in this but I'm guessing that this may be a way to go if I find pliers with thinner ends.

Comment: Does the screw have sides to it like a hex head?

Comment: Have you tried just pulling down? Maybe they are clips not screws

Comment: It's probably some kind of tamper proof screw.  Can you take a better picture of the screw and make a drawing?

Comment: @Steven, I can't pull it down as it's in rather narrow slot so there is no way to grab it easily.

Comment: @WarLoki not really it looks more like nail with a head cut from two sides.

Comment: @steven, if those are like the ones I had in my stair (in Edinburgh, incidentally), they're screws.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - the lamp is located in Edinburgh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your stair, lighting might be the responsibility of the council. If there's a sticker/notice that has a number for "concerns/ complaints", they'd be the right ones to call. If there's nothing posted, it might be a communal thing. Part of the reason I bring this up is that the replacement bulbs for that lamp seemed really expensive when bought in small quantities. (Or maybe that was just me being a cheapskate. From memory, it was just shy of a tenner.)

But a pair of small-ish needlenose pliers should allow you to unscrew them. If you're naughty, replace with a normal bolt.

If your ceiling is high, be careful on that ladder.

Comment: Thanks, actually someone fixed it yesterday. Out of curiosity, how much is the bulb?

Comment: How much? Now that you ask, I'm doubting my memory. I think each unit took two bulbs at 4 or 5 pounds each.